# How modify properties of a input in a sidebar on shiny R

Tags: css, r, input, shiny, sidebar

I'm trying to extend my sidebar and inputs, but my css doesn't work.

```
 dashboardSidebar(       
              width = 500,
                withMathJax(),
                   sliderInput(inputId = "alpha", "mysliderInput",
                               label=(helpText(c("Escolha o valor de $\\alpha$:"))),
                               min = 0.01, max = 10, value = 3.48, step = .1,
                               animate = animationOptions(interval = 300, loop = T)),
                   sliderInput(inputId = "delta", "mysliderInput",
                               label=(helpText(c("Escolha o valor de $\\delta$:"))),
                               min = 0.01, max = 10, value = 0.88, step = .1,
                               animate = animationOptions(interval = 300, loop = T)),
                   sliderInput(inputId = "sigma", "mysliderInput",
                               label=(helpText(c("Escolha o valor de $\\sigma$:"))),
                               min = 0.01, max = 10, value = 2.06, step = .1,
                               animate = animationOptions(interval = 300, loop = T)),
                   sliderInput(inputId = "gama", "mysliderInput",
                               label=(helpText(c("Escolha o valor de $\\gamma$:"))),
                               min = 0.01, max = 10, value = 2.97, step = .1,
                               animate = animationOptions(interval = 300, loop = T)),
                   sliderInput(inputId = "eta", "mysliderInput",
                               label=(helpText(c("Escolha o valor de $\\eta$:"))),
                               min = 0.01, max = 10, value = 4.98, step = .1,
                               animate = animationOptions(interval = 300, loop = T)),
                   sliderInput(inputId = "lambda", "mysliderInput",
                               label=(helpText(c("Escolha o valor de $\\lambda$:"))),
                               min = 0.01, max = 10, value = 9.8, step = .1,
                               animate = animationOptions(interval = 300, loop = T)),
             tags$head(
                tags$style(HTML("#mysliderInput{width: 500px;}}"
                )))
```

),

I want to change width and font-size.
[My sidebar code with inputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MA6Hd.png)

Comment: Can you provide `ui` and `server` code required for the question to be completely reproducible along with necessary data if required?

Comment: have you tried with width='500px'  in sliderInput() instead of doing it with css? anyway, you are using "mysliderinput" like a class or id, when it's neither in this context, the argument it's correspond in your code is "min".

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use the `sliderInput` width argument. Here's a minimal example:

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- dashboardPage(dashboardHeader(),
                    dashboardSidebar(       
                        width = 500,
                        sliderInput(inputId = "alpha", "mysliderInput",
                                    label=(helpText(c("Escolha o valor de $\\alpha$:"))),
                                    min = 0.01, max = 10, value = 3.48, step = .1, width = '500px',
                                    animate = animationOptions(interval = 300, loop = T)) 
                    ),
                    dashboardBody()
                    
)

server <- function(input, output) {}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thank's that worked